# Clipboard text/html not pasting into Slack message

Tags: javascript, clipboard, slack

The `clipboardItem` below does not paste into a message in the Slack App.

```
const htmlContent = 'Hello <a href="https://world.com">world</a>';

const blob = new Blob([htmlContent], { type: 'text/html' });

const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blob });

navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Copied to clipboard.');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed:', error);
  });
```

But if I paste `clipboardItem` into a Gmail draft and then highlight and copy it, it does paste into a message in the Slack App.

How can `clipboardItem` be pasted into a message in the Slack App while: 1) retaining the formatting in `htmlContent` and 2) being paste-able into a Gmail draft with that formatting?